# I cannot read when typing (reading and editing only upon successive submissions)

Tags: support, feature-request, usability

My posts are frequently hijacked by comments:

- "Stop typing and start reading"
- "don't make so many revisions"

Generally understanding these cyclic worries,  I should explain that I cannpt do any of this,
because I do not see rendering pane of my typing  after first dozen lines due to:

- "Related Question" above editor textbox occupies all screen
- the editing textbox is not adjustable in sizeand is too short in height

and rendering pane disappear from view after a dozen lines...

**And this all having multimonitor with 3 monitors of 17", 22" (the height is the same as 17") and 15"!**

Possible solutions are easy, one would suffice:

- to make the editing and rendering panes, "Related Questions"  adjustable in size and movable
- etc.

**As an urgent measure**,

- just to place rendering pane to the right of editing textbox (but not beneath), side by side and make them higher and narrower,
- to move "Related question" beneath  "How to format" (appearing during typing) or above

**OR**

- provide **"Preview" button**

Update:
I would like to thank all participants.
This is the first time in my life I observe so many talented educated individuals to gather together in order to unanimously and brilliantly prove banalities to one worthless individual.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: At that point, I just scroll down... I see a scroll bar on the right...

Comment: Hundreds of posts? I see 25 questions and 36 answers as of this writing. That looks like < 100 to me. You may very well have hundreds of edits - but this is partially where your downvotes come from. You consider an edit to a post a new post, when really edits were never intended to add content, but rather to add clarity and fix typographical errors.

Comment: it's a problem when an "IT professional" such as yourself doesn't even comprehend the concept of scrollbars.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what your issue is. Below the text input field, there is a preview field. I can see the bottom of it in your screen shot.

If you want to type an extremely long question and don't feel like scrolling up and down, why not type the content into word/notepad/whatever and paste it in and then just add the formatting?

Comment: That's often what I do, use an external editor.  I didn't really think about it until you mentioned it.